# How do I use link_to image_tag to retrieve a path from a field within my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails, I am trying to create a news aggregation site similar to digg.com.  When a user clicks on a thumbnail I would like the URL for the source website to launch.

Right now my code opens the URL within my application that created the "listing". I have a field within the "listing" called "source" that contains the URL of the news source. Could someone tweak my link_to image_tag so that clicking on the thumbnail launches the "source" field within the "listing"?

```
  <% @listings.each do |listing| %>

    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="thumbnail">

        <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url), listing %>
```

Comment: `<%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url), listing.source, target: "_blank" %>`

Comment: thank you Pardeep. That gets me halfway there.  If my "source" is cnn.com, the html that is generated includes the the path of my application and then adds cnn.com on the end.  Ex.  http://tenacious-dragon-14-134879.use1-2.nitrousbox.com/cnn.com  Is there away to get it to go directly to cnn.com.  my application gives  a routing error that says No route matches [GET] "/cnn.com"

Comment: Thanks Pardeep. I've got it figured out.  I needed http:// before the URL and then it handled it fine.  I appreciate your help so much.

Comment: Because your answer came in the form of a comment, I cannot mark your answer as the correct answer. Feel free to enter your comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: good to hear its working for you..I added answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `listing.source` will return you site url you want to move and `target: '_blank'` will open link in new tab.

```
<%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url), listing.source, target: "_blank" %>
```